# which is faster in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

which is faster in MYSQL:

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= ENT_DATE
```

or

```
'2014-04-06 00:00:00'<= ENT_DATE
```

?

In admin `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)` is giving me faster result.

Comment: What is `ENT_DATE`? How are you determining which is faster?

Comment: it depends on what '2014-04-06 00:00:00' is... like what is the datatype? if its recognized as a datetime object, then it will be faster because you aren't doing the calculations in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Both comments are accurate...  What is the data type of "ENT_DATE", and also is it part of an index or just by itself as it's own index.

The more critical thing I would comment on is that you do not do functional conversion of the date field as the index won't be able to optimize against it.  The format you have it via the parameter as a fixed string in a date format, or date_sub() computed value they should be the same.  Either way... a string to date/time conversion, or via a function to subtract dates... the time would be minimal, then applied to the index to retrieve the data.